# Exponential of a Hamiltonian Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian

I am trying to understand a problem which involves a two-level system given by:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
C1(t) \\
C2(t) \\
\end{pmatrix}=e^{-i\hat{H}t/2}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
I am being asked to compute:
$$
\hat{M}=e^{-i\hat{H}t/2}$$ 
by using the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem for matrix exponentials
where $$\hat{H}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues for this particular matrix are: $$\lambda=5,-2$$
I am confused because according to CH,
$$e^{At}=a\hat{I}+b\hat{A}$$
and,$$e^{\lambda t}=a+b\lambda$$
The following is shown in the solutions:
$$e^{-i5t/2}=a+5b$$$$e^{-i(-2)t/2}=e^{it}=a-2b$$
My confusion is with the setup of the above equations, as they seem to ignore the general format according to CH. Does the minus sign in front of $\hat{H}$ not matter? By extension, does the $-i/2$ not matter either?
My attempt looked like this for what it's worth: $$e^{-i5t/2}=a-\frac{5i}{2}b$$$$e^{-i(-2)t/2}=e^{it}=a+ib$$ Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take

$$b^{\prime}=-\frac{i}{2}b$$

then your equations are as given in the solution. Notice that you'll always be able to do this substitution.

Comment: If I make this substitution, I can go about solving the rest of the problem as I normally would? So essentially what this means is that only the eigenvalues matter, because once I find $a$ and $b'$ and solve for $\hat{M}$ that's that, they are no longer needed.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can you demonstrate what do you mean?

Comment: Okay so you said we can make the substitution $b'=-\frac{i}{2}b$ and that will yield the same equations as in the solution. From there I can find $a$ and $b'$, which is what I need to find $\hat{M}$. What I am asking is that when I go to find $\hat{M}$, how does that substitution impact my answer? To find $\hat{M}$ I need $a$ and $b$. Do I back-substitute at this point and carry on? $\hat{M}$ is not in the same format that CHT talks about, so I am now confused about how move forward with $a$ and $b'$. I hope that wasn't too confusing.

Comment: The most "correct" way is to use $-\frac{5}{2}i$ and $i$ as eigenvalue. Using $5$ and $-2$ just means you are assuming $e^{At}=aI-\frac{i}{2}bH$ with $A=-\frac{i}{2}H$.